# i get System.MissingMethodException in winCE - C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce

what this exception:

System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
Message: File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

how i can fix it ?

thank's in advance

Comment: You could start by telling us what you're trying to do when you get the error. Please post some code - ideally a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you reference an assembly that has not been deployed to the device. Is the .Net compact framework version 3.5 installed on your device?